# Save NpgsqlPoint (Postgresql Point) With Entity Framework

Tags: c#, postgresql, postgis, npgsql

I am trying to save a Point Type into Postgresql
I have tried this way.
(Db table Model definition)

```
 public NpgsqlPoint Position { get; set; }
```

I set the Object with this method

```
  posData.Position = new NpgsqlPoint (34.3244,23.2344);
```

But when i call .SaveChanges on the dbContext i get an exception of 
Not Null Constraint Violation , so  i guess EF is trying to insert a null.

I have debuged the posData.Position before entry and the object contains proper data.

I have searched google but i didn't find any example or someone having the same problem.

Any Clues?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update :**

Full Native PostGIS for Npgsql is shceduled to be released with version 3.1.
Quote from npgsql.org [version 3 release notes.](http://www.npgsql.org/npgsql-3.0-released/)

> Major goals for Npgsql 3.1 includes:
>       Full, native PostGIS support (#529)

And for those who want to keep up with the changes. [Here is the feature branch conversation](https://github.com/npgsql/npgsql/issues/529).
Support for 2D PostGIS is already merged to default.

**For Npgsql version 2.x here is my old answer.**

I Posted the question in Npgsql Development forum , and got my answer.

NpgSqlPoint type is not yet Supported by EF due to Entity Framework Data type Restriction.

Seems they are still working on this one.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like `NpgsqlPoint` makes a [PostgreSQL `point` type](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-geometric.html). This is *not* the same as a [POINT `geometry` type](http://postgis.net/docs/reference.html#Geometry_Constructors) used by the PostGIS Extension (e.g., `geometry(Point, 4326)`).

To make a PostGIS `geometry`, you will need `x`, `y` and `srid` (spatial reference ID; e.g. see http://spatialreference.org/). These can be used with a [ST_MakePoint](http://postgis.net/docs/ST_MakePoint.html) geometry constructor, and [ST_SetSRID](http://postgis.net/docs/ST_SetSRID.html) to establish the spatial reference. For example, here's a parameterized command:

```
SELECT ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(:long:, :lat:), 4326)
```

which assumes a WGS84 coordinate (SRID=4326).

Comment: Yes I am Actually Trying to insert a normal postgres "point" type.
When i make the variable "String" and pass "12.5454,41.1215" for example the point gets saved successfully . But then i have problem reading the point as string from Entity Framework which returns  just the class name as value.

Comment: Ok, the `postgis` tag suggested that you were using PostGIS.